# How can I set specific download URI for file?

Tags: 7, files, multi-sites

Here is my problem. I've got file (eg. some.xml) and multisite Drupal 7 installation.
How can I allow to download this xml from my-multi-site.domain/some.xml?
Is there any way to do it without writing custom module with hook_menu?

P.S. this file should be different for every site on multisite installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to solve this problem by serving this file through nginx. 
That is not a universal solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is a hook_menu, which I believe is also going to be a requirement to make this reasonable when several sites want separate names.

I workaround would be to just symlink it to your Drupal root.

```
ln -s sites/example.com/files/somefile.xml some.xml
```

But if it's a requirement to have each filename only available on one domain, apache would need to have logic to block the "wrong" names, which is inconvenient.

A third possibility would be to rewrite the URL in apache, but I don't exactly know the syntax for this.

Comment: I've forgot to mention, but this file should be different for every site, however thanks for answering.